# How to get Authorization token of AWS Amplify in postman?

Tags: aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I could able to get Authorization token of AWS amplify by using the following code `await Auth.currentSession()).idToken.jwtToken`. I am using this in my react native. Now I am creating postman collection for my app and I am not able to generate the Authorization Code in the postman. I didn't find any docs related to it. Can anyone please guide me on how to generate the Authorization Code?